# HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() connection gets actively refused in executable but not in WPF standalone application

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am working with web server to make calls to its API via HttpWebRequests. I wrote a standalone WPF application for testing purposes and all of my requests were functioning correctly. When I referenced the working project file in my production application it is now returning that the request is being actively refused by the server.

```
public string Post(string xmlData, Transaction transaction)
{
        var result = "";

        try
        {
            var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl);
            webReq.Accept = "application/xml";
            webReq.ContentType = "application/xml";
            webReq.Method = "POST";
            webReq.KeepAlive = false;
            webReq.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            webReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

            // If we passed in data to be written to the body of the request add it
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData))
            {
                webReq.ContentLength = xmlData.Length;
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webReq.GetRequestStream())) /**CONNECTION REFUSED EXCEPTION HERE**/
                {

                    streamWriter.Write(xmlData);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            else //Otherwise write empty string as body
            {
                webReq.ContentLength = 0;
                var data = "";
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webReq.GetRequestStream()))
                {

                    streamWriter.Write(data);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }

            //Attempt to get response from web request, catch exception if there is one
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var streamreader =
                    new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
                {
                    result = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //Handle web exceptions here               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle other exceptions here
        }
    }
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Can you run Fiddler and compare requests between WPF and your standalone apps?

Comment: POST http://192.168.1.186:44000/URTConnector HTTP/1.0
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: 192.168.1.186:44000
Content-Length: 323

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urtMessage>
 <side>Left</side>
 <commandRequest xsi:type="URT_CommandRequest_RegisterClient" id="1995090047" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <timestamp>2019-01-18T14:32:29.2982855-05:00</timestamp>
  <remove>false</remove>
 </commandRequest>
</urtMessage>

Comment: POST http://192.168.1.86:44000/URTConnector HTTP/1.0
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: 192.168.1.86:44000
Content-Length: 322

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urtMessage>
 <side>Left</side>
 <commandRequest xsi:type="URT_CommandRequest_RegisterClient" id="107882392" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <timestamp>2019-01-18T14:35:14.4098680-05:00</timestamp>
  <remove>false</remove>
 </commandRequest>
</urtMessage>

Comment: First following comment was an unsuccessful request copied from raw view of Fiddler, second was a successful request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing your fiddler requests I can say that the reason is probably the IP address difference.

You use `192.168.1.186:44000` first time and `192.168.1.86:44000` second time.

Comment: Thank you, guess I was blind to that while trying to track down other avenues.